# How to obtain SIMBA SPARK ODBC Driver Version 1.0.8?

Tags: hadoop, driver, tableau-api, simba

Currently, I’m using Tableau 9.3, to work with Hadoop environment I need  **SIMBA SPARK ODBC Driver Version 1.0.8**. If anyone has it please share a link to download it.

Comment: I would not recommend that you accept driver code that is emailed to you. Aside from the fact that private support requests are off-topic here, there is no way you can sensibly trust emailed binaries. How would you know that such a file does not contain malicious code?

Comment: Have you searched for this file yourself? Where would you normally expect to download it from?